# Can I update colors on animation in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I tried to make animation to change its theme (ex: Background.Color property) dynamically in WPF app.
The theme is switched by switching the resource dictionaries: SolidColorBrush, Color and Storyboard are on it.
Here is [a reference site](http://www.markodevcic.com/post/Changing_WPF_themes_dynamically/).

When a resource dictionary is switched, brushes on controls are switched, but for some reasons I have not found how to switch themes in storyboards.

Some reasons are:

1. Storyboard in WPF seems not to support dynamic resource.
2. Static resources that referenced by storyboards are not updated even if the resource dictionary is switched dynamically.

Does anyone know how to do it, or whether it is possible/impossible ?

Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is _yes_

Comment: Can you show me how to do it, please ?

Comment: Look into ColorAnimation